# How do I debug my Android app on Samsung

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-4.2-jelly-bean, samsung-mobile

I am trying to debug my first app. I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android Jelly Bean (I'm a Windows user) and I have installed the latest version of Kies and have installed all required drivers for my device.

---

Following the steps to debug in the Android Getting Started tutorial, I have not been able to successfully debug my app on my phone or in an emulator.

Actually I don't really care fo the emulator at this point since this app is just a hello world app. I need to see it on my device but I can't and I don't know what I'm doing wrong, if anythin.

When I hit the debug button in `Android Studio`, and select my Device as the device to debug on from the popup dialog, Android Studio then displays the following error:

> Installing myapplication
>   DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r
>   "/data/local/tmp/myapplication"
>   pkg: /data/local/tmp/myapplication
>   Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]

I have searched this error but all the solutionts I have seen are telling me to do things I've already done!

How can I debug an app on Samsung GS3 using Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats your package name ?
You must have one "." at least

Comment: My package name was MyApplication. I went to project pane, right-clicked > Refactor > Rename > "com.MyApplication" then saved then debugged but it still gave the same error.

Comment: I just created a whole new project, and put com.application as package name and it worked :-D Thanks @marshallino :D

Comment: Yes, the problem was the capitalized letter "M" and "A". You can have capitalized letters, but only after the second "." according to the Java RFC.